# Compute the perimeter density matrix

Tags: code-golf, matrix

### Introduction

The *perimeter density matrix* is an infinite binary matrix **M** defined as follows.
Consider a (1-based) index **(x, y)**, and denote by **M[x, y]** the rectangular sub-matrix spanned by the corner **(1, 1)** and **(x, y)**.
Suppose that all values of **M[x, y]** except **M<sub>x, y</sub>**, the value at index **(x, y)**, have already been determined.
Then the value **M<sub>x, y</sub>** is whichever of **0** or **1** that puts the average value of **M[x, y]** closer to **1 / (x + y)**.
In case of a tie, choose **M<sub>x, y</sub> = 1**.

This is the sub-matrix **M[20, 20]** with zeros replaced by dots for clarity:

```
1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

For example, we have **M<sub>1, 1</sub> = 1** at the upper left corner, since **1 / (1 + 1) = ½**, and the average of the **1 × 1** sub-matrix **M[1, 1]** is either **0** or **1**; that's a tie, so we choose **1**.

Consider then the position **(3, 4)**.
We have **1 / (3 + 4) = 1/7**, and the average of the sub-matrix **M[3, 4]** is **1/6** if we choose **0**, and **3/12** if we choose **1**.
The former is closer to **1/7**, so we choose **M<sub>3, 4</sub> = 0**.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQB48.png) is the sub-matrix **M[800, 800]** as an image, showing some of its intricate structure.

### The task

Given a positive integer **N < 1000**, output the **N × N** sub-matrix **M[N, N]**, in any reasonable format.
The lowest byte count wins.

Answer (score 3):

## R, <strike>158 154</strike> 141  bytes

Edit: Because the only `1` in the upper `2x2` submatrix is the top left `M[1,1]` we can start the search for `1s` when `{x,y}>1` so no need for the `if` statement.

```
M=matrix(0,n<-scan(),n);M[1]=1;for(i in 2:n)for(j in 2:n){y=x=M[1:i,1:j];x[i,j]=0;y[i,j]=1;d=1/(i+j);M[i,j]=abs(d-mean(x))>=abs(d-mean(y))};M
```

The solution is highly inefficient as the matrix is duplicated twice for each iteration. `n=1000` took just under two and a half hours to run and produces a matrix of `7.6` Mb.

**Ungolfed and explained**

```
M=matrix(0,n<-scan(),n);                        # Read input from stdin and initialize matrix with 0s
M[1]=1;                                         # Set top left element to 1
for(i in 2:n){                                  # For each row    
    for(j in 2:n){                              # For each column
        y=x=M[1:i,1:j];                         # Generate two copies of M with i rows and j columns
        x[i,j]=0;                               # Set bottom right element to 0
        y[i,j]=1;                               # Set bottom right element to 1
        d=1/(i+j);                              # Calculate inverse of sum of indices
        M[i,j]=abs(d-mean(x))>=abs(d-mean(y))   # Returns FALSE if mean(x) is closer to d and TRUE if mean(y) is
    }
};
M                                               # Print to stdout
```

Output for `n=20`

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
[1,]     1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[2,]     0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[3,]     0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[4,]     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[5,]     0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[6,]     0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[7,]     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[8,]     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
[9,]     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[11,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[12,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[13,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[14,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[15,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[16,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[17,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[18,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[19,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[20,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <del>129</del> <del>119</del> <del>117</del> 115 bytes

- Replaced the loop with a list comprehension so everything can go on one line and can be lambda
- Replaced .append() with :=z+[]
- -2 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat for pointing out that `(1+a)*(1+c) = (-a-1)*(-b-1)`
- -1 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat for removing the 0 from .5
- -1 byte thanks to @thonnu for a more efficinet way to do `and z` at the end.

```python
lambda x,z=[]:[z:=z+[~(i//x)*~(i%x)/(i//x+i%x+2)>=sum(z[k]&(k%x<=i%x)for k in range(i))+.5]for i in range(x*x)][-1]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZY1BCsIwEEX3PcVstJlGrRYEKcaLxCwqNhprorQpxC68iJuC6J28jakKgv7Nm3l8-Jf78WS3B9NeJVveaiuHs0e1z_RqnYEbNIyLlDcpayg_ExXHDiPPnsP49VF_0gQXrKo1aXgh-qTouTnrGvJQQgHKQJmZTU4UIh1NRWfV17rIoeDDifhM1xoYJOPAekiiMfjpa0wD8On07l93OZbKWBK6EJQEy1Wk6U5Avq9yCCEc5GbNPDH4dvE93rZvPgE)

Rust is no longer better than python. Port of my Rust answer. Outputs a flattened matrix

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <del>118</del> 111 bytes

```python
def f(x,z=[]):
 for i in range(x*x):z+=[~(i//x)*~(i%x)/(i//x+i%x+2)>=sum(z[k]&(k%x<=i%x)for k in range(i))+0.5]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZU_LCsIwELznK_ZSm22qLYIgxfgjpQfBRGNNWtoIsQd_xIsX_Sf_xsQHgs5ldodhZvd8a49225jL5Xqwcjy_N2shQVKXDryssCAgmw4UKAPdymwEdYnDYmC8PFGVZQ4Tz5HD7LkxP7IpLnl_0HQo62pE68gteHCEnPqboxBZPplV71qngcM0J9a3Ekl1apH8NOtwjUeQd_9yQNspY2nsYlASbKkSzXYViH0vIIY4FWbNPSP5evHV_3n_AQ)

Thanks to @xnor and @ceilingcat. Outputs my modifying the input in place.

Comment: [117 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY7dCsIwDIXv@xS5mWvW4fxBELG@yNiFsFa72W50HdS@/GzxYqCHwAlfwknGt3sO5nge7bK0QoKkHi8EAq8bAnKwoEAZsHfzENQXcRYY31c0FVNV5ZF928wj3vg0axrqvtnQPvNXnmjK6NcMhci2p5KAFW62BsKigcNhR1w0STWSn6M6vROVcPePk0arjKO5z0FJcLUqNOsaEK9JQA55KUzLoyNZd3H5AA "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online") I think I/O defaults also allow taking in `z=[]` as input and modifying it without returning.

Comment: [115 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZY1BCsIwEEX3PcVstJlGrQiCFONFYhYVG401UdoUYhZexE1B9E7exlQFQf_mzTw-_Mv9eLLbg2mvki1vjZXD2aPe53q1zsENPOMi4z5jnvIzUWnqMAnsOUxfHw0nneCC1Y0mnpeiT8qem7OuIQ8VlKAMVLnZFEQh0tFUdFZ9rUscimRM_We60cBgMo5sgCQao5--xiyCkE7v_nWXY6WMJbGLQUmwXCWa7gQU-7qAGOJBYdYsEKNvF9_jbfvmEw) (includes @ceilingcat's suggestion)

Comment: `z[k]>(k%x>i%x)` saves a byte, switching `z` from list to tuple saves another (`lambda x,*z:`/`z:=z+(...,)`)

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 36 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
+`⁼{˘>(⊣-⌊`∘-)`<˘⌊0.5+(×÷+)⌜˜1+↕}
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgK2Digbx78J2UvfCdlL3LmD4o4oqjLeKMimDiiJgtKWA8y5jijIowLjUrKMOXw7crKeKMnMucMSvihpXwnZWpfQoKRiAyMAoK)

Two observations:

- Minimizing distance of mean to `1/(x+y)` is the same as minimizing distance of sum to `x×y/(x+y)`.
- At least up to 1000×1000, which is maximum size required in the challenge, there is no row or column with two ones.

The function performs three major steps:

`⌊0.5+(×÷+)⌜˜1+↕` Generate matrix **round(x×y/(x+y))**.

`` (⊣-⌊`∘-)`<˘ `` Calculate matrix **sum(M[x, y])**.

`` +`⁼+`⁼˘ `` Convert that to the *perimeter density matrix* by performing *inverse cumulative sum* (`` +`⁼ ``) on rows and columns.

This runs reasonably fast, generating the full 1000x1000 in ~60ms locally, but some less golfed version were a bit faster.

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>565</del> <del>476</del> <del>460</del> <del>458</del> <del>447</del> 440 bytes

Golfed version. [Attempt this online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZHdasIwFMfZm5Rencyate5mGCMbuItdFC92KTKiTW1KPqRNh1V8kt3IYHuGPYtPs7QR2c0gJOfkd77yz8d3vWaS3Z9OX43Nhw_nm59HxYQOMp4Hih7emQw07WOwMPjVZi8aV5y5wwIiHU7pU1WxFpt8JtTC3S9BRxqRFGLkFk1IbioQk2ESNNoKV4-UfxzU99jTFNdSrDnEkRgkvvKO7rFiW3i7otIhz9p_2A4EghLRmLQXK-njM5rg-A7EoByMutk8Ezkw2EUZmjBo3YHigMuaB8mRpNiNzdm6AEOnB3P1JJ1uK-Fe73LlJEEhDn2Ka94DqSEM0RGRTkIGatzLs_B7J88yysYz06wkR1QxW2C2qiG7VVhyvbGFMwon8HxrhdGXN3qC8IbbefXs2jlhhwrnklnLNa4bhY7-Ay__ePocxd76BQ)

Saved 125 bytes (565->440) thanks to the comment of [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

```scala
@main def m={val n=scala.io.StdIn.readInt();val M=Array.ofDim[Int](n,n);M(0)(0)=1;for(i<-1 until n;j<-1 until n){val z=M.slice(0,i+1);val x=z.map(_.slice(0,j+1));val y=z.map(_.slice(0,j+1));x(i)(j)=0;y(i)(j)=1;val d=1.0/(i+j+2);M(i)(j)=if(a(x,d)<a(y,d))0 else 1};M.foreach(o=>{o.foreach(l=>print(if(l<1)"."else 1));println("")});def a(m:Array[Array[Int]],d:Double)=math.abs(d*m.length*m.headOption.map(_.length).getOrElse(0)-m.flatten.sum)}
```

---

Ungolfed version. [Attempt this online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVNLTsMwEJVY5hSjrmygJoENqigSAhYsIhYsEUJu47SuHDtyXEiFOAmbCgkOxWVgHLvhu0FK4vjNvHnzsZ9emylX_GC9flm6cnj4tvUuq9pYBx3OpGFXrrjQzAqOi0sSM1mIqYOcSw2idUIXDZzUNTwkAHdcgYYxRGdCI5YjdmItXzFTnsnqGm03RO-C9g45SSk-6JIluC2NBSLhaAgZLLWTGJF2waNp8acp6LQYJGeNklNB0l2QsAMZZRWvye0nuuhQ-oW2-j-tJZKShU86jciqR7IvoQu_Zyns-Zp2uiD7NIkOeU-RJZCKuznjk4YUMIRKcE1aSuF4DL8NK4qWDIRqRNR_TPy7aZ81975L-bfGCSU8iLbPpnldj4-xDgq1lTi0ARvQEDrsM9orQICUJoMB3SgWogxZYZ5WtqMw6evw9ZO-oSM4M8uJ14nKvjWYyKnBMUJXITKZEnrm5r3D1KgfDnM8V5e1k0bH6QQGZTPhLu055owHqeNHQqm4wyPKmmXFnIlJ7HUNCqG3e5VQz2MS7kG8Duvn_TT8fQA)

```scala
import scala.io.StdIn.readInt

object Main extends App {
  val n = readInt()
  val M = Array.ofDim[Int](n, n)
  M(0)(0) = 1

  for (i <- 1 until n) {
    for (j <- 1 until n) {
      val x = M.slice(0, i + 1).map(_.slice(0, j + 1))
      val y = M.slice(0, i + 1).map(_.slice(0, j + 1))
      x(i)(j) = 0
      y(i)(j) = 1
      val d = 1.0 / (i + j + 2)

      M(i)(j) = if (math.abs(d - mean(x)) >= math.abs(d - mean(y))) 1 else 0
    }
  }

  for (row <- M) {
    for (ele <- row) {
      if (ele == 0) print(".") else print(1)
    }
    println("")
  }

  def mean(matrix: Array[Array[Int]]): Double = {
    val rowCount = matrix.length
    val colCount = matrix.headOption.map(_.length).getOrElse(0)
    matrix.flatten.sum.toDouble / (rowCount * colCount)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you do `import io.StdIn._` instead?

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 189 Bytes

There  are no crazy tricks in here, it is just calculating as described in the introduction. It isn't particularly quick but I don't need to create any new matrices to do this.

```python
n=input()
k=[n*[0]for x in range(n)]
for i in range(1,-~n):
 for j in range(1,-~n):p=1.*i*j;f=sum(sum(k[l][:j])for l in range(i));d=1./(i+j);k[i-1][j-1]=0**(abs(f/p-d)<abs(-~f/p-d))
print k
```

Explanation:

```python
n=input()                                     # obtain size of matrix  
k=[n*[0]for x in range(n)]                    # create the n x n 0-filled matrix
for i in range(1,-~n):                        # for every row:
  for j in range(1,-~n):                      # and every column:
    p=1.*i*j                                  # the number of elements 'converted' to float
    f=sum(sum(k[l][:j])for l in range(i))     # calculate the current sum of the submatrix
    d=1./(i+j)                                # calculate the goal average
    k[i-1][j-1]=0**(abs(f/p-d)<abs(-~f/p-d))  # decide whether cell should be 0 or 1
print k                                       # print the final matrix
```

For those curious, here are some timings:

```python
 20 x  20 took 3 ms.
 50 x  50 took 47 ms.
100 x 100 took 506 ms.
250 x 250 took 15033 ms.
999 x 999 took 3382162 ms.
```

"Pretty" output for `n = 20`:

```python
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 152 bytes

```rust
|z|{let mut b=vec![];for i in 0..z*z{b.push(((1+i/z)*(1+i%z))as f32/(i/z+i%z+2)as f32>=(0..i).map(|d|(d%z<=i%z&&b[d])as u8 as f32).sum::<f32>()+0.5)};b}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZBLbsIwEIbXySkmkUDjpIQ0bSWUB8foBrEgEKtGeSBid-HE96jUDYv2UByid6hN0oqizmY03_wznt_vH0fR8tN5RmuoNqxGAp0NAGXBgca0RhmLlsmCzJbPxTbNm6ZcQvYpOJ0tzm-97DujrASHPHstts5qndDmCAxYDWEQSE92eXAQ7Qsi3vtsLoln8kQSsmmBPkRz1NAAPxrJMkM9yUhQbQ7Y73rcTWSaacV0mq92a6MSCxi0JGhFFcepGUPih8ETUUmuxvu-7MR4uZjhkMFjmNi_oNKAIieD5HBkNS9rB8f62gQfvmQI09hfNSzLYhSqFfO4v18PwLpsc9Dt4jSMlHvH9FaNFRRlW9xoANzxzZ9Qfyqw_2vc3qvs0fTpNORv)

Lots of wasted space due to needing `as f32` everywhere :(

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 294 bytes

```
(define(g x y)(if(= 1 x y)1(let*((s(for*/sum((i(range 1(add1 x)))(j(range 1(add1 y)))#:unless(and(= i x)(= j y)))
(g i j)))(a(/ s(* x y)))(b(/(add1 s)(* x y)))(c(/ 1(+ x y))))(if(<(abs(- a c))(abs(- b c)))0 1))))
(for((i(range 1(add1 a))))(for((j(range 1(add1 b))))(print(g i j)))(displayln""))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define(f a b)  
  (define (g x y)
    (if (= 1 x y) 1
        (let* ((s (for*/sum ((i (range 1 (add1 x)))
                             (j (range 1 (add1 y)))
                             #:unless (and (= i x) (= j y)))
                    (g i j)))
               (a (/ s (* x y)))
               (b (/ (add1 s) (* x y)))
               (c (/ 1 (+ x y))))
          (if (< (abs(- a c))
                 (abs(- b c)))
              0 1))))
  (for ((i (range 1 (add1 a))))
    (for ((j (range 1 (add1 b))))
      (print (g i j)))
    (displayln ""))
  )
```

Testing:

```
(f 8 8)
```

Output:

```
10000000
00000100
00100000
00000000
00001000
01000000
00000000
00000000
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 151 + 1 = 152 bytes

Run with the `-n` flag.  The code will only work correctly every *other* iteration within the same instance of the program.  To get it to work correctly every time, add 5 bytes by prepending `my%m;` to the code.

```
for$b(1..$_){for$c(1..$_){$f=0;for$d(1..$b){$f+=$m{"$d,$_"}/($b*$c)for 1..$c}$g=1/($b+$c);print($m{"$b,$c"}=abs$f-$g>=abs$f+1/($b*$c)-$g?1:_).$"}say""}''
```

Readable:

```
for$b(1..$_){
    for$c(1..$_){
        $f=0;
        for$d(1..$b){
            $f+=$m{"$d,$_"}/($b*$c)for 1..$c
        }
        $g=1/($b+$c);
        print($m{"$b,$c"}=abs$f-$g>=abs$f+1/($b*$c)-$g?1:_).$"
    }
    say""
}
```

Output for input of 100:

```
1___________________________________________________________________________________________________
_____1______________________________________________________________________________________________
__1_________________________________________________________________________________________________
___________________________1________________________________________________________________________
____1_______________________________________________________________________________________________
_1__________________________________________________________________________________________________
_________________________1__________________________________________________________________________
_________________1__________________________________________________________________________________
______________1_____________________________________________________________________________________
____________1_______________________________________________________________________________________
__________1_________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_________1__________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
________1___________________________________________________________________________________________
______________________________________________________________________________________1_____________
_________________________________________________________________1__________________________________
_______1____________________________________________________________________________________________
_____________________________________________________________1______________________________________
____________________________________________________1_______________________________________________
______________________________________________1_____________________________________________________
__________________________________________1_________________________________________________________
_______________________________________1____________________________________________________________
____________________________________1_______________________________________________________________
__________________________________1_________________________________________________________________
______1_____________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
___1________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
________________________________1___________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
________________________1___________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_______________________1____________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
______________________1_____________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
___________________________________________________________________________________________________1
_____________________1______________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_____________________________________________________________________________________1______________
__________________________________________________________________________________1_________________
____________________1_______________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
________________________________________________________________________________1___________________
______________________________________________________________________________1_____________________
___________________________________________________________________________1________________________
_________________________________________________________________________1__________________________
___________________1________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_______________________________________________________________________1____________________________
______________________________________________________________________1_____________________________
____________________________________________________________1_______________________________________
___________________________________________________________1________________________________________
__________________________________________________________1_________________________________________
_________________________________________________________1__________________________________________
__________________1_________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
________________1___________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
________________________________________________________1___________________________________________
_______________________________________________________1____________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
___________________________________________________1________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
__________________________________________________1_________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
________________________________________________1___________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_____________________________________________1______________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________1_______________________________________________________
_______________1____________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_________________________________________1__________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 180 bytes

```
(a=SparseArray[{1,1}->1,{#,#},-1];({x,y}={##};If[(t=a[[##]])<0,s=0;Do[If[{i,j}!={##},s+=#0[i,j]],{i,#1},{j,#2}];l=s(q=1/x/y)-1/(x+y);r=l+q;a[[##]]=If[Abs@r>Abs@l,0,1],t])&[#,#];a)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5NT8QgGIT/CpakAfvWgh6RhiZe9GBM9ogcUFvtpl9LObQh/PaKGy8zkyeTyYzW/7Sj9f2nPTp5ECtPi3Vr2zhndx048FjWHAIGHKHkRpCwwR5lwDiK504TL63WGBtDHxmskomnWSceejjHm2sN1kJiphMwBhLHPEI4A76PRgxyJRfJq63aackrshU7FU4OxUX8z8o01nysytV/OgADbsAbmut0yQhL8@PN9ZNXJ5/s@2XuJ90sSzt9pQLK3qfMoBxVCpHX2Y12UJ16YKi6Q4GjskbZbQaIXRPKIjXHLw)

Recursive approach: start from array filled with undefined `-1` items and `1` for first item.
For `n` 20-30 as faster, as Python.
Full version self-explained:

```
Clear[m];
n = 15;
arr = SparseArray[{1, 1} -> 1, {n, n}, -1];
m[x_, y_] :=
  If[(current = arr[[x, y]]) < 0,

   total = 0; Do[total += m[i, j], {i, x}, {j, If[i == x, y - 1, y]}];
   tmp1 = total/x/y - 1/(x + y); tmp2 = tmp1 + 1/x/y;
   arr[[x, y]] = If[Abs@tmp2 > Abs@tmp1, 0, 1]
   
   , current
   ];
m[n, n];
StringJoin[Append[#, "\n"] & /@ (Normal@arr /. {1 -> "*", 0 -> " "})]
```